# git clone для проекта с подмодулями

Tags: git, git-clone, git-submodule

Пытаюсь выполнить

```
git clone --recursive "/c/Users/user/projects/main" .
```

Выдает

```
Cloning into '.'...
done.
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'submodule-folder' in .gitmodules
```

Основной проект в папке main. 
Внутри этой папки лежит вложенный проект в main/submodule-folder. 
Со своим репозиторием.
После создания вложенного проекта - сделал коммит с добавлением подмодуля в основной проект (тот что в папке main).

---

Как в этом случае склонировать проект с подмодулями? 
Нужно ли создавать файл .gitmodules? Как?

UPD1.
Вариант c --recurse-submodule тоже не помог

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules "/c/Users/user/projects/main" новПроект6
Cloning into 'новПроект6'...
done.
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'submodule-folder' in .gitmodules
```

Или в другом варианте

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules=yes "/c/Users/user/projects/main" новПроект7
error: option `recurse-submodules' takes no value
usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
```

Comment: склонировать репу с сабмодулями - `git clone --recurse-submodules=yes <url>`

Comment: Советую сто раз подумать, перед тем как серьёзно использовать подмодули. Их очень сложно готовить. Тривиальные checkout между ветками могут стать болью. Лучше использовать любой другой менеджер зависимостей и подтягивать зависимости из другого репозитория.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за совет. Но у меня это решение пока не заработало. В чем я могу ошибаться? Подробности добавил в текст вопроса.

Comment: напишите без `=yes`. `git clone --recurse-submodules <url>`. Оно менялось и в одних версиях было так, в других - по другому. я не помню, когда оно поменялось.